# YouTube videos opening unexpectadly and blocking mobile device

Tags: html, css, video, youtube

This is the html to display 3 videos on the screen. When this is viewed on a mobile device (e.g. Samsung S8), the screen automatically activates.

```
<div class="row bottom-whitespace">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <figure class="img-tbtext video-icon">
        <div class="vid-banner"><img src="../assets/images/video-img1.jpg" class="hover-img">
        <div class="lazyOwl"><img src="../assets/images/play-Icon.png"></div>
        </div>
        <a class="gallery" data-flashy-type="video" href="https://youtu.be/ZfDRNqWfGas" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></a>
        <h5>Change, project and task management</h5>
         </figure>
       </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4">
        <figure class="img-tbtext video-icon " style="background: #ffc107;">
         <div class="vid-banner"><img src="../assets/images/video-img2.jpg" class="hover-img">
        <div class="lazyOwl"><img src="../assets/images/play-Icon.png"></div></div>
        <a class="gallery" data-flashy-type="video" href="https://youtu.be/MY_CFDnNTzU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></a>
        <h5>Process excellence & waste management</h5>
         </figure>
       </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4">
        <figure class="img-tbtext video-icon" style="background: #8bc34a;">
         <div class="vid-banner"><img src="../assets/images/video-img3.jpg" class="hover-img"><div class="lazyOwl"><img src="../assets/images/play-Icon.png"></div></div>
        <a class="gallery" data-flashy-type="video" href="https://youtu.be/gYfdvWWf1p8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></a>
        <h5>Quality control, Audit and Quality assurance</h5>
         </figure>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Autoplay Videos**

In Safari and some other browsers(mobile), autoplay for videos are prevented and an active input from a user is needed. Safari and Chrome decide that on an algorithm which depends on your browser behaviour:

Safari: https://www.cnet.com/news/wwdc-privacy-high-sierra-safari-blocking/

Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Can you give us some reproducible code? This way we can check what goes on and maybe find your problem. :)